# Using Mongoid tree for many to many relationships in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I just wanted to seek some advice on database design with mongoid and rails.

If I have complex objects that need the ability to reference each other, would this be an appropriate solution.

```
class Tree
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Tree
end

class Group < Tree
end

class People < Tree
end

class Cars < Tree
end

etc...
```

So they can all belong to each other, be siblings or be children.  Would this improve performance as they would all be in the same collection? Compared to if I was to use a habtm relationship between say 2, 3 or 4 models. Not entirely sure if separate models called in the same collection is faster or an appropriate design.

The main reason I tried this design was because I was reading the the idea behind nosql is to use nest objects to minimize calls to the database.  Does it make any difference referencing a child object in the same collection compared to a separate collection?  Or even across multiple collections?

There's a few questions here but hopefully someone could help point me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, good choice! You want to use Inheritance like this to store them in the same collection.
You'll only have to access one collection - which should make it faster accessing children / parents.

Comment: I also wanted to ask if it would be also a good idea to have users in the same collection or in their own collection?

Comment: I thought your question was more like a toy example... hmm... having People, Groups and Cars in one collection is probably not a good idea in a real-world application. You need to check what the relations between the models are. Typically things which are unrelated are separate top-level collections.  Things that depend on  something else could be embedded documents, or referenced documents.